# Perform priority query in Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Ihave this table in database :

http://screencast.com/t/aT2uM5p0

And i have list priority contains ids of priority images. I need to perform query to get all images from this table , order by date added and images with ids from priority list must to be on the top of the list after query and order by date added to.

for example : if i have in database images with ids: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. , added to database in this order, and i have priority list with ids : 3,5. So i need to get list of images in this order : 3,5,1,2,4

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach.

If I assume that you have the two lists called `images` (already sorted in the "non-priority" fashion) and `priorityIds` then this could work for you:

```
var sortMap =
    priorityIds
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .ToDictionary(xn => xn.x, xn => xn.n);

Func<int, int> sortFunc = n =>
{
    if (sortMap.ContainsKey(n))
    {
        return sortMap[n];
    }
    return int.MaxValue;
};

var query =
    from i in images
    orderby sortFunc(i.Id)
    select i;
```

The result of running `query` gives you the ordering that you want. The use of the dictionary should make this quite fast too.